# Access variable from a static function in php

Tags: php

Here is a program from php. I am not able to print the value of the protected variable  from a static function. What is wrong with this program?

```
class SomeClass
{
    protected $_someMember;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_someMember = 1;
        self::getSomethingStatic();
    }

    public static function getSomethingStatic()
    {  
        echo $_someMember * 5; 
    }
}
$obj = new SomeClass();
```

Comment: you cannot access instance variables from static functions

Comment: `static` == no object instance. No instance, no `$this`. No object, no `$this`, no **instance variables**.

Comment: So you have 10 different objects. Which one's `$_someMember` are you expecting to see there? Another point - you have no objects at all - what's in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You expect to do something like this

```
class SomeClass
{
    protected static $_someMember = <default value>;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::getSomethingStatic();
    }

    public static function getSomethingStatic()
    {  
        echo static::$_someMember * 5; 
    }
}
$obj = new SomeClass();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to take a look at PHP's documentation on [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). As you should note that static functions can NOT access object properties.

In fact, if you are trying to learn the ins & outs of PHP's OOP implementation, you may want to look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Right need to go through some documentation.